# How to specify modality with Jpa entities?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to generate database schema using Spring Data Jpa.
I wonder if there is a way to specify modality in the relationship between two entities.

Currently it's mandatory relationship

[image: img-1]

What I want to achieve is making it optional.

[image: img-2]

My code, I configured for unidirectional many to one relationship.

```java
@ManyToOne(optional = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "photographer_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private User user;
```

I'm aware that `optional = true` only for hibernate runtime instruction. I need changes in database level.

Comment: As far as I remember, relationships by default are optional and nullable, so you wouldn't need to do anything to make the schema generation not create constraints. You could try `@JoinColumn(nullable = true, ...)` in conjunction with your `@ManyToOne(optional = true)` to assert this.

Comment: Yeah they are both default behaviors, but they are only in hibernate level, the relationship in database schema is otherwise mandatory. I'm trying to find the annotation or property to set the relationship from mandatory to optional in database level.

Comment: Well, you could always override the column definition with `columnDefinition = "int null"`, but that would be database-dependant and thus not recommended. Could you try upgrading your dependency versions? Because I couldn't reproduce your scenario.

Comment: ummm.. sorry I don't understand your mean on upgrading dependency versions :(. What i'm trying to do is, currently it's each user need to have at least one package(service package), I need it to be each user can have 0 or many package. I could have defined the schema first, but I want to achieve this with hibernate.